# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError dynamic reactive forms

Tags: angular

This exception occurs when using nested reactive forms, when the child component uses ng-if*. It's the template interpolation that causes problems. Please see repro:

https://plnkr.co/edit/GrvjN3sJ05RSNXiSY8lo

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-nested-component',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="parentForm">

    <input formControlName="mynestedcontrol" type="text">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class MyNestedComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() parentForm:FormGroup
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.parentForm.addControl("mynestedcontrol", new FormControl('',[]))
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  template: `<div [formGroup]="parentForm">

    <input formControlName="mycontrol" type="text">
    <a href="#" (click)="onClickShowDetails()" *ngIf="!showDetails">Show Details</a>
    <div *ngIf="showDetails">
      <my-nested-component [parentForm]="parentForm"></my-nested-component>
    </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class MyForm implements OnInit {
  @Input() parentForm:FormGroup
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.parentForm.addControl("mycontrol", new FormControl('',[]))
  }

  showDetails = false;

  onClickShowDetails() {
    this.showDetails = true
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
      <my-form [parentForm]="myForm"></my-form>
    </form>

    {{myForm.value|json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  myForm:FormGroup
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({})
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule],
  declarations: [ App,MyForm,MyNestedComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We run into a problem with this error again and again...

Basically many people don't want to understand what is the cause of this error. And as a result we see a lot of answers where the main solution is calling second lifecycle digest. But in some cases it won't help.

Angular change detection is comprehensive mechanism. In order to achieve insight you have to work with it every day and have to debug it again and again.

First, i strongly suggest you reading this great article by @angularindepth-com

- https://blog.angularindepth.com/he-who-thinks-change-detection-is-depth-first-and-he-who-thinks-its-breadth-first-are-both-usually-8b6bf24a63e6

Now, the truth Is out there...

I created one more component like:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-info',
  template: `{{form.value|json}}`
})
export class MyFormInfoComponent {
  @Input() form: FormGroup
}
```

and added it to the root html instead of interpolation:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
  <my-form [parentForm]="myForm"></my-form>
</form>
<my-form-info [form]="myForm"></my-form-info>
```

Now angular doesn't complain about that error because i've changed change detection order.

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/aOOyxD3rBNXGi4Eiytbu?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

See also

- [Catch Angular template errors like a pro or how I create Angular Demo](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/catch-angular-template-errors-like-a-pro-or-how-i-create-angular-demo-e98694977911)

Comment: I appreciate your answer and references. I do wonder though if there's anything inherently wrong with my code. As a framework user, I feel like I shouldn't need to take into account how Angular's change detection algorithm is implemented

Comment: Yes, i know it hard to follow angular concepts. There is nothing wrong in your code, angular was simple designed this way. Maybe it will be changed soon and we will not need to take care of such cases anymore.

Comment: Another dumb question- any harm to simply ignoring this error (if that's even possible)?

Comment: Very rare but sometimes you can get inconsistent data.Most often this is a harmless error. It does not appear in prod mode